# Why cocos2d-x schedule changed the member object?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have these two classes in cocos2d-x project:

```
class A : public Layer
{
    ...
    B * b;
    void callAddNumber(float dt);
}

A::A()
{
    b = B::create();
}

void A::callAddNumber(float dt)
{
    b->addNumber();
}


class B : public Node
{
    ...
    int number;
    B();
    void addNumber();
}

B::B()
{
    number = 100;
}
void B::addNumber()
{
    number += 1;
}
```

and A object call `shschedule(schedule_selector(A::callAddNumber), 1.0f);`
but number do not add as I expected; it seems after I scheduled, the b object becomes released? The b->number becomes a garbage number? Why does this happen?
I am sure that I initialized the `b`in A 's constructor.

Comment: You don't show the code that allocates or otherwise initializes the `B *b` in your `class A`, which is probably where the trouble occurs.  It isn't clear how you'd access the number from the `B` type; presumably, you do have some way of doing so (because you need to be able to print the number).  But on the basis of the code that's (not) shown, the trouble is most probably in the constructor for `class A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not show the relevant code.

In general ::create() returns a pointer to an AutoRelease object. This object will be released by next frame unless somebody retains() it first.

All objects that inherit from Ref are expected to be created on the heap and memory managed using retain()/release() policy.
That is anyone who wants to keep a reference to them must call the method `retain()` when he accepts the reference and remember to call `release()` when it is destroyed or before it releases the object.

On ::create() an object is added to an autoRelease Queue. This is a queue of objects that will all be released on before the next frame. So unless someone calls ::retain() before that happens the object is released.

(You can use an intrusive smart pointer wrapper to make all this bookkeeping go away)